# Creating a deck of cards using a class array?

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to VB. I am having trouble using a `class` `(a card class I created)` into another `class` `(Deck class)`.  I am not sure on how to get and set array property's once I have created my fields.

### Here is the code for my card class

```
Namespace Game Public Class Card 

'create fields Private cardValue As Integer Private cardSuite As String

Property CardValue_Prop() As Integer
    Get
        Return cardValue
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        cardValue = value
    End Set
End Property

Property CardSuite_Prop() As String
    Get
        Return cardSuite
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        cardSuite = value
    End Set
End Property

Sub New(cardValue As Integer, cardSuite As String)
    Me.cardValue = cardValue
    Me.cardSuite = cardSuite
End Sub

End Class
End Namespace
```

Here is the start of my deck class - I basically want to make all the card objects (all the cards in the 52 card deck):

```
Namespace Game 

Public Class Deck 'create fields 

Private spades(12) As Card 

Private Hearts(12) As Card 

Private Diamonds(12) As Card 

Private clovers(12) As Card

ReadOnly Property Spades_Prop(---------) As Card  <-- stuck here
      Get
          Return 
      End Get
   End Property
End Class
End Namespace
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:
I wouldnt use 4 arrays. Rather use one array of card and add a 'suit' to class card.

```
Namespace Game Public Class Card 

'create fields Private cardValue As Integer Private cardSuite As String

...
Public Property Suit as Suit
Get
 Return _suit
End Get
End Property
...

End Class
End Namespace
```

Define Enum Suit:

```
Public Enum Suit
   Spades
   Diamonds
   Hearts
   Clubs
End Enum
```

And then in your main class game:

```
Namespace Game 

Public Class Deck

Private _cards(51) As Card 

Public ReadOnly Property Cards() As Card()  <-- here is your answer
Get
  Return _cards 
End Get
End Property 
End Class 
End Namespace
```

Also, you were really close to the answer. You just had to add two brackets to define it's an array.

Comment: A deck of cards doesn't hold 53 cards;) Change to `Private _cards(52 - 1) As Card`.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå thanks. I always get mixed up with Java :(

Comment: Hehe, you're not alone;)

Comment: 0-51 my bad.  Thank you.  I really wanted to practice creating my own class and using it in another user defined class.

Comment: Fabian when I enter ReadOnly Property Cards()() As Card <-- I get an error that says End of Statement expected anda blue line under () As Card

Comment: Ah sorry i think i fixed it now